# Forward Rest calls inside the container to wiremock running on host machine

Tags: docker, junit, docker-compose, wiremock

I have spring boot application which does Rest calls running in a docker container. I want to forward those Rest Calls to the host machine running wiremock and send JSON back to the application running on the container. Is this possible? I have tried publishing the port like below in my docker-compose file, but no luck there.

ports:
- "127.0.0.1:9233:9233"

Below is the exception I get.

Caused by: org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: CRLF expected at end of chunk
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:253)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:225)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.close(ChunkedInputStream.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ResponseEntityProxy.streamClosed(ResponseEntityProxy.java:143)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkClose(EofSensorInputStream.java:228)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:172)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.close(InflaterInputStream.java:227)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.close(GZIPInputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.close(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:94)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implClose(StreamDecoder.java:378)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.close(StreamDecoder.java:193)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.close(InputStreamReader.java:199)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.close(BufferedReader.java:525)
    at com.isirona.drivers.welchallyn.sdk.com.types.JSONCom.callJSONService(JSONCom.java:91)
    ... 7 common frames omitted

Comment: The answer will most likely be "yes", but the real question is: "_what isn't working for you?_"

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: The rest calls are not reaching my wire mock server.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring the URL like http://host.docker.internal:8080
Enter the port number on which your wiremock server is running instead of 8080.